# AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter triggered no matter what SecurityFilterChain it is a part of

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am experimenting with spring security and came across a strange behavior.
My idea is to create a security filter that authenticates requests based on JWT (or JWS) tokens:

```
public class JWTokenFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    public JWTokenFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super("/**"); //doesn't have any effect, every request still gets considered by this filter
        setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        String token = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (!StringUtils.hasText(token)) {
            throw new TokenException("Token is empty");
        }
        var authentication = determineAuthentication(token.replace("Bearer","").trim());
        //the AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter fills the Security context
        return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authentication);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean requiresAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        System.out.println("Asked for "+request.getRequestURI());
        return request.getHeader("Authorization") != null;
    }


    private TokenAuthentication<UserInfo> determineAuthentication(String token) {
        var split = token.split("\\.");
        if (split.length < 2 || split.length > 3) {
            throw new TokenException("Token malformed");
        }
        if (split.length == 2){
            return new JWTAuthentication<>(token);
        }else {
            return new JWSAuthentication<>(token);
        }
    }

}
```

I have 3 `@RestController` classes which have their paths mapped:

1. `@RequestMapping("/admin")`
2. `@RequestMapping("/all")`
3. `@RequestMapping("/anon")`

Along with this, I have the following security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@Order(98)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/all/**","/anon/**")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/all/**").permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/anon/**").anonymous();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring().mvcMatchers("/webjars/**", "/css/**");
    }



    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Configuration
    @Order(99)
    public static class TokenSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

        @Lazy
        @Autowired
        private JWTokenFilter tokenFilter;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests() //having /admin/** or /** makes no difference
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and().addFilterBefore(tokenFilter,ExceptionTranslationFilter.class);//put this filter near the end of the chain
        }

        @Bean
        public JWTokenFilter tokenFilter(JWTokenAuthenticationProvider jwTokenAuthenticationProvider,JWSTokenAuthenticationProvider jwsTokenAuthenticationProvider){
            var list = new ArrayList<AuthenticationProvider>();
            list.add(jwsTokenAuthenticationProvider);
            list.add(jwTokenAuthenticationProvider);
            ProviderManager manager = new ProviderManager(list);
            return new JWTokenFilter(manager);
        }
    }
}
```

From this configuration here we can see that there are 2 `SecurityFilterChan`s (not counting the `/webjars` and `/css` ones):

1. That matches all requests for `"/all/**"` and `"/anon/**"` REST routes
2. That matches any request

Since the 1. chain has lower `@Order(98)`, than 2. `@Order(99)`, that means that the **1.** chain **will be considered first** which is shown by the debugger,
[image]

and matched if the **incoming request** looks like:

```
curl --request GET \
  --url http://localhost:8080/all/hello \
```

Now what I am experiencing is that the `JWTokenFilter` method `boolean requiresAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)` **is always called no matter the request path !**
And in the console output, I can find `Asked for /all/hello`.

Edit:
My spring boot version is `2.3.6.RELEASE`

---

My question is:

Why is the `JWTokenFIlter` even asked if it should authenticate requests with paths that are not matched by the `SecurityFilterChain` it is a part of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I have a better answer, but I wanted to answer your original question as well. I split this into two sections.

**Improved Answer**

I realize this doesn't answer the original question, but I think you may be better off using the built in support for JWT based authentication. I'd check out the [OAuth 2.0 Resource Server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.4.x/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver) section of the reference documentation.

**Answer to Original Question**

Spring Boot [will automatically register](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-embedded-container-servlets-filters-listeners-beans) any `Filter` exposed as a `@Bean` for every request directly with the Servlet Container.

You have two options that I see. The first is to avoid exposing the `JwtTokenFilter` as a `@Bean`.

```
@Configuration
@Order(99)
public static class TokenSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    @Autowired
    JWTokenAuthenticationProvider jwTokenAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    JWSTokenAuthenticationProvider jwsTokenAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests() //having /admin/** or /** makes no difference
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().addFilterBefore(tokenFilter(),ExceptionTranslationFilter.class);//put this filter near the end of the chain
    }

    
    public JWTokenFilter tokenFilter(){
        var list = new ArrayList<AuthenticationProvider>();
        list.add(jwsTokenAuthenticationProvider);
        list.add(jwTokenAuthenticationProvider);
        ProviderManager manager = new ProviderManager(list);
        return new JWTokenFilter(manager);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can continue exposing `JwtTokenFilter` as a `@Bean` and create a `FilterRegistrationBean` [that disables registration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-disable-registration-of-a-servlet-or-filter).

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean registration(JWTokenFilter filter) {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
    registration.setEnabled(false);
    return registration;
}
```